# Select parent jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in programming and I hope you guys help me out of this. I want to change the background color of `class="menu a"` on event is clicked on .`submenu li a`.

Code:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu").click(function(){
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).children().show();
    });
    $(".submenu li a").click(function(){
    $(".submenu li a").css("color","blue");
    $(this).css("color","red");
    $(this).parent(".menu a").css({"background": "green"});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">link 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">inlink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inlink 2</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">link 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">inlink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inlink 2</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.*** You need to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), because `menu` is not a direct parent of  `submenu li`

***2.*** On `submenu li` click, first remove background color from other `menu a` and then add background color to current clicked  parent `menu a`

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu").click(function(){
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).children().show();
  });
  $(".submenu li a").click(function(){
   $('.menu').children("a").css({"background": "white"});
    $(".submenu li a").css("color","blue");
    $(this).css("color","red");
    $(this).closest(".menu").children("a").css({"background": "green"});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">link 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">inlink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inlink 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">link 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">inlink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inlink 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you tell me why you use a:first

Comment: @VarunSharma  its my mistake, which i corrected in my edit. That's not necessary(As it's not wrong, but not necessary)

Comment: @VarunSharma  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use this:

```
$(this).parent('.menu a')
```

Problem is, `.menu a` isn't its parent. Only `.menu` is. `a` is a child of `.menu` (like an uncle to `.submenu li` ;)).

Instead, use:

```
$(this).parent('.menu').children('a')
```

First you find the parent `.menu`, then find its direct child `a`. `children()` (as opposed to `find()`) will ensure you only get the direct child, not the ones that are down in `.submenu`.

Answer (score 0):

use `closest` instead of `parent`

`$(this).closest(".menu").find("a").css({"background": "green"});`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using closest()

```
$($(this).closest(".menu a").css({"background": "green"});
```